# Button in CSS3 not clickable

Tags: html, css

I want to make some fancy social buttons with [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), CSS3 and lists in HTML. It should look like this. But now it is not possible to click on the anchor (a-tag).

How can I accomplish this?

```css
ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #099;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
li::before {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 35px;
}
ul li a {
    color: transparent;
    font: 0px/0 a;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="menu-social" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-googleplus" class="fa fa-google-plus menu-item menu-item-googleplus">
    <a href="#">Google+</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-facebook" class="fa fa-facebook menu-item menu-item-facebook">
    <a href="#">Facebook</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add position relative to the li elements and then stretch the anchor.

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #099;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;

    /* Add position */
    position:relative;
    }

ul li a {
    color: transparent;
    font: 0px/0 a;
    white-space: nowrap;

   /* Stretch a element */
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my browser (Firefox) the a-tag has filled up the screen and only the Facebook-button is clickable. I want both buttons to be clickable and only as big as the parent tag.

Comment: @Josjojo Please check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/6kphso0u/2/)